# How can I generate a paged table with a title in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I have a `data.frame` that I want to print in an RMarkdown document (HTML output) in a formatted way. There are 3 features I need for it which I haven't been able to get at the same time:

1. It needs to have a title or caption at the top to explain what it is.
2. Since it may be very long, I want it to be scrollable or paged
3. The caption and column headers should always be visible at the top, even when the table is scrolled or paged

---

I can get the caption with scrolling easily with `kableExtra`:

```
library(kableExtra)
cars %>%
    kable(caption = 'Cars') %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c('striped', 'condensed')) %>%
    scroll_box(width = "500px", height = "200px")
```

But when I scroll down, the caption and column headers scroll too, and it's hard to see what each column is.

---

By adding `df_print: paged` to the YAML header, I can get a really nice looking paged output (see [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#data-frame-printing)) from the default printing behavior:

````
---
title: "Motor Trend Car Road Tests"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
cars
```
````

But, so far as I know, there is no way to put a title or caption on this. I could just add a title using markdown, but then the code to generate the table would be stuck between the title and the table. Any other options that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest trying `DT::datatable`, which produces highly configurable tables in html output.

The following code will create a scrollable table with a fixed header.

```
DT::datatable(mtcars, 
         extensions = c('FixedColumns',"FixedHeader"),
          options = list(scrollX = TRUE, 
                         paging=FALSE,
                         fixedHeader=TRUE))
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with. It's funny, I've used `DT` a lot in shiny, but didn't think of using it RMarkdown.