# Why is my RMarkdown paging every table in Editor but not in knitted document (HTML)

Tags: r, r-markdown, editor

I would like to see my output in the editor as a long long tibble with all rows at once. But instead my RMarkdown decides to page the tibble with 10 rows per page. I transformed it into a data.frame but it didn't change anything. In the knitted document it is as one long tibble, but not in the editor. I tried the chunk option results = "asis" but that didn't work either. I read about that there is the rmarkdown of paged_table(), but I think this is for the HTML output, where it maybe should be fine paged, but in my editor i want it as one long tibble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print.data.frame` to display all the rows.

````
```{r}
print.data.frame(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I recall adding `df_print: paged` to the YAML section (see below) would resolve this issue. But, I just tried it and it did not help.

```
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
```

Based on the discussions on [How can I generate a paged table with a title in RMarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52877741/how-can-i-generate-a-paged-table-with-a-title-in-rmarkdown), I used this to solve the same problem that I had:

```
DT::datatable(data,
              options = list(scrollX = TRUE, paging=TRUE))
```